# Two-way cluster-robust standard errors produce NA standard errors in R - why?

Tags: r, standard-error

I use Arai's (2015) method (specifically, the mclx function on page 4) to produce cluster-robust standard errors for my lm in R  (http://www.ne.su.se/polopoly_fs/1.216115.1426234213!/menu/standard/file/clustering1.pdf).

I use panel data and try to produce two-way cluster-robust standard errors (by year and by country).

My problem is that while I get the coefficient estimates for every independent variable, I get NAs for standard errors, t stats, and p values FOR SOME (not all) variables.

I checked related topics but could not find an answer to this problem. In particular, it has nothing to do with the data structure since all data are "numeric", it is no multicollinearity issue, there are enough observations per cluster dimension (i.e., year and nation)...

The mclx() function looks as follows:

```
    ### Write function for Multiple dimension SE clustering
mclx <- 
    function(fm, dfcw, cluster1, cluster2){
        library(sandwich)
        library(lmtest)
        cluster12 = paste(cluster1, cluster2, sep="")
        M1 <- length(unique(cluster1))
        M2 <- length(unique(cluster2))
        M12 <- length(unique(cluster12))
        N <- length(cluster1)
        K <- fm$rank
        dfc1 <- (M1/(M1-1))*((N-1)/(N-K))
        dfc2 <- (M2/(M2-1))*((N-1)/(N-K))
        dfc12 <- (M12/(M12-1))*((N-1)/(N-K))
        u1 <- apply(estfun(fm), 2, 
                    function(x) tapply(x, cluster1, sum))
        u2 <- apply(estfun(fm), 2, 
                    function(x) tapply(x, cluster2, sum))
        u12 <- apply(estfun(fm), 2, 
                    function(x) tapply(x, cluster12, sum))
        vc1 <- dfc1*sandwich(fm, meat=crossprod(u1)/N)
        vc2 <- dfc2*sandwich(fm, meat=crossprod(u2)/N)
        vc12 <- dfc12*sandwich(fm, meat=crossprod(u12)/N)
        vcovMCL <- (vc1+vc2-vc12)*dfcw
        coeftest(fm, vcovMCL)
    }
```

Then, I specify my multivariate linear model and call the results:

```
### cluster on two variables (year and anation)
mclx(fm, 1, data$year, data$nation)
```

Unfortunately, I have no permission to post the data here. And the problem does not occur when I use Arai's (2015) provided test data, but I cannot figure out the problem with my data. So, maybe someone has a general idea why some parameter estimates for standard errors, t stats, and p values produce NAs and how to avoid this? I'd be very grateful for any hint...

Comment: Hard to tell without a reproducable example. Maybe you have NA values in vectors `data$year`, `data$nation` that go into your `mclx()` function but are excluded from your `fm`model. Check lengths of both vectors (eg `length(data$year)`) and compare to `nobs(fm)`.

Comment: ups, and `any(is.na(data$year))`

Comment: Hi Helix123, thanks for the quick response. I can confirm that there are no NA values in vectors (data$year, data$nation). 
Maybe this helps: I get the warning "Warnmeldung:
In sqrt(diag(se)) : NaNs wurden erzeugt" (warning: in sqrt(diag(se)): NaNs have been created). Does this help somehow? Thanks again...

Comment: Both any(is.na(data$year))  and any(is.na(data$nation)) return "FALSE"...

Comment: Maybe no NAs in `year` and `nation`, do lengths match? Guess the warning that comes from taking a square root of a negative number, (try eg. `sqrt(-1)`). Thus, try to find the place where variable `se` is created and go backwards from there (`se` seems to be in a different function)

Comment: You could try using `cluster.vcov` from CRAN package `multiwayvcov` instead. Maybe that avoids the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The formulae seem right and the data is also unproblematic. However, some values in the variance covariance matrix still have negative signs. I simply modify Arai's method for my purpose by taking the VCV values to the square and then I take the square root. This eliminates the problem and the se should be correct.